# How to find max of time increase occurs consecutively in last 12 month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i try to find max of time increase occurs consecutively in last 12 month. i can't figure out how to code.
sample data as below

|  | date | account_no | is_bucket | pre_bucket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-31 | 000000001 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-09-30 | 000000001 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-10-31 | 000000001 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2022-11-30 | 000000001 | 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 2022-12-31 | 000000001 | 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 2023-01-31 | 000000001 | 1 | 5 |
| 7 | 2023-02-28 | 000000001 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 2023-03-31 | 000000001 | 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 2023-04-30 | 000000001 | 4 | 3 |
| 10 | 2023-05-31 | 000000001 | 5 | 4 |
| 11 | 2023-06-30 | 000000001 | 6 | 5 |
| 12 | 2023-07-31 | 000000001 | 7 | 6 |

i use code but this can't separate 2 period  for find max

```
   WITH temp_cal AS (
      SELECT DATE_KEY,
            ACCOUNT_NO,
            ROWNUM,
            current_bucket,
            previous_bucket, 
            IF(current_bucket > previous_bucket, TRUE, FALSE) AS is_increase,
            LAG(IF(current_bucket > previous_bucket, TRUE, FALSE),1,FALSE) OVER (partition by ACCOUNT_NO ORDER BY DATE_KEY) AS pre_increase
      FROM (
         SELECT DATE_KEY,
               ACCOUNT_NO,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NO ORDER BY DATE_KEY) AS ROWNUM,             
               bucket_order AS current_bucket ,
               LAG(bucket_order,1,1) OVER (partition by ACCOUNT_NO ORDER BY DATE_KEY) AS previous_bucket
         FROM `nano-business.risk_temporary.RISK_B2_PNE_OBS`
         
      )   
   )
   SELECT *,
          COUNTIF((current_bucket > previous_bucket)) OVER (partition by ACCOUNT_NO ORDER BY DATE_KEY ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS COUNT_INC 
   FROM temp_cal
   ORDER BY ACCOUNT_NO, DATE_KEY , COUNT_INC
```

|   |date           |account_no     |is_bucket |pre_bucket  |max_incre
|1  |2022-08-31 |000000001  |1     |1           |0
|2  |2022-09-30 |000000001  |2     |1           |1
|3  |2022-10-31 |000000001  |3     |2           |2
|4  |2022-11-30 |000000001  |4     |3           |3
|5  |2022-12-31 |000000001  |5     |4           |4
|6  |2023-01-31 |000000001  |1     |5           |4
|7  |2023-02-28 |000000001  |2     |1           |4
|8  |2023-03-31 |000000001  |3     |2           |4
|9  |2023-04-30 |000000001  |4     |3           |4
|10 |2023-05-31 |000000001  |5     |4           |4
|11 |2023-06-30 |000000001  |6     |5           |5
|12 |2023-07-31 |000000001  |7     |6           |6

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query being used does calculate a running count of increases, but it doesn't handle separating the periods of increase.

Let's use the sequence of is_bucket to demonstrate: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7.

There are two periods of increase here: 1 2 3 4 5 and 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. The current code does not separate these two periods and instead treats them as one long sequence. Therefore, the maximum count of increase it would return would be the total length of the sequence.

To solve this problem, we need to reset the count whenever there's a decrease or a plateau in the is_bucket value. This way, we can identify distinct periods of increase and determine the maximum length among them.

Here's a modified SQL query that accomplishes this. It adds a new column group_id to separate periods of increase. This group_id increments whenever the current bucket is less than or equal to the previous bucket:

```
    WITH temp_cal AS (
    SELECT 
        DATE_KEY,
        ACCOUNT_NO,
        ROWNUM,
        current_bucket,
        previous_bucket,
        IF(current_bucket > previous_bucket, TRUE, FALSE) AS is_increase,
        LAG(IF(current_bucket > previous_bucket, TRUE, FALSE),1,FALSE) OVER (partition by ACCOUNT_NO ORDER BY DATE_KEY) AS pre_increase,
        SUM(IF(current_bucket > previous_bucket, 0, 1)) OVER (partition by ACCOUNT_NO ORDER BY DATE_KEY) AS group_id
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            DATE_KEY,
            ACCOUNT_NO,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NO ORDER BY DATE_KEY) AS ROWNUM,             
            bucket_order AS current_bucket ,
            LAG(bucket_order,1,1) OVER (partition by ACCOUNT_NO ORDER BY DATE_KEY) AS previous_bucket
        FROM `nano-business.risk_temporary.RISK_B2_PNE_OBS`
    )   
)
SELECT *, COUNTIF((current_bucket > previous_bucket)) OVER (partition by ACCOUNT_NO, group_id ORDER BY DATE_KEY) AS COUNT_INC 
FROM temp_cal
ORDER BY ACCOUNT_NO, DATE_KEY , COUNT_INC
```